# Peak Analysis of Density Histogram - R

Tags: r, density-plot

I'm working with the R language and I had to plot the density comparison of two samples:

samples1:

```
id1 2

id2 2

id3 2

id4 2

id5 2

id6 2

id7 3

id8 3

id9 3

id10 2
```

and samples2:

```
id1 1

id2 1

id3 1

id4 1

id5 1

id6 1

id7 1

id8 2

id9 2

id10 1
```

The first column is the ID's and the second column is the VALUES of that ID.

Ex.:

Id1 - value.

Id2 - value.

...

- Note that the two samples have the same size and the same ID's, but different values.

I used the following code to plot this image:

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(sm)
library(scales)

x <- data.frame(read.table("C:/Users/Filli/Desktop/pasta/samples1.txt"), type = "Agregado")
y <- data.frame(read.table("C:/Users/Filli/Desktop/pasta/samples2.txt"), type = "Temporal")

data <- rbind(x,y)


print(ggplot( data, aes(x = V2, group = type)) +  geom_density(aes(fill= type), size=0, alpha=0.7))
```

http://prntscr.com/fdespg

What I would like is, how do I find out the id's of the peaks of each density (in red and blue)? In the case, for example, I would like to find the id's that are contained within the red rectangle in the image above for each density (red and blue). I do not want to plot the red rectangle, it was just to illustrate. What I want is to get the id's from each peak (in red and blue) and compare them to see if the i'ds are the same. Consider that there is only one large peak for each density. I want to get only the largest id's from each peak (like the image above) and compare them to see if they are the same or different.

Comment: Maybe something like `maxID1 <- df1$ID[df1$val == max(df1$val)]` and similar with df2. Then you could use `intersect` to find overlaps or `setdiff` or `setequal`. You will probably have to convert these vectors to character with `as.character`.

Comment: I think that's wrong! Beacuse, the density calculation is different from what you did, so the result is wrong: S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the base R `density` function, which `ggplot` uses for density charts.  To find the location of the peak, for example, you could use

```
density(data$V2)$x[which.max(density(data$V2)$y)]
```

See `?density` for more details.

Comment: Using density(data$V2)$y[which.max(density(data$V2)$y)] I have: 0.5186269. What's the 'id' with this density ?

Comment: That first `$y` should be `$x` to give the x-location of the peak.  Your value is the maximum height of the density curve.

Comment: How do I get the "id" this value?

Comment: You are graphing and applying the density to `V2`, not to the `id`s.  The peak is the value of `V2` with the highest density - the ids are just names for sample points.  Perhaps you need to redraft the question as it is not clear what you are looking for.  This sort of density does not necessarily make sense for discrete variables - it is treating V2 as a continuous variable.